# Is it safe to make a null reference check like if(component) on Unity GameObjects/Components?

Tags: unity, c#

I was reading that Unity does not store GameObjects being `null` literally, but instead overloads the `==` operator.

For this reason the null coalescence operators `??` `??=` don't work on GameObjects or Components

But if GameObjects and Components are never set to the literal value `null`, and instead `==` is overloaded, is it unsafe to do a null check
`if(component != null)` as `if(component)`?
The latter option compiles and seems to work fine, but I don't understand why if it's not ever the value `0`, and if this will actually cause problems down the line

Comment: If you're trying to skip the overloaded comparison operator, (and you're sure you're not dealing with an object that might have been `Destroy()`ed or filled-in by an editor placeholder) you can also use `System.Object.ReferenceEquals(myComponent, null)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because `GameObject` inherits `Object` that implements a conversion to bool, [`Object.bool`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html), which is what gets evaluated when you write `if (object)`.

The linked docs assert that the conversion behaves equally to `operator!=` which I assume in any sane world of boolean axioms behaves as `!(operator==)`, meaning that the conversion behaves as `operator==`, not as `System.Object.ReferenceEquals(gameObject, null)`.

Comment: Does this implicit conversion behave like the overridden `==` operator and report "false" for objects that have been `Destroy()`ed? Or does it behave like `System.Object.ReferenceEquals(gameObject, null)` and return false only for a "real" `null`?